# Retrieving a database value and assigning to a string value

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a app that incorporates login/register functionalities and I'm making a issue that I have been trying to solve.

When a user logins and the login is successful, I'd like to use the email that they signed in with to pass to the next activity using Intent (I checked that the email is in fact getting passed by displaying what is being passed through the intent) and then passing that email to a function in the Dbhelper that uses that email to look for the name of the person that signed in then displaying "Welcome (name of person)" in the current activity but I keep getting a null returned in the function which ultimately leads to the app crashing.

Here is where I'm calling the function in the activity where I want to display the name.

```
if(!session.loggedIn())
        {
            Logout();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent in  = getIntent();
            String email = in.getStringExtra("email");
            Name.setText("Welcome " + db.findName(email));
        }
```

And this is the function in my DbHelper.java where I'm looking for the name with a query and such.

```
public String findName(String user_email)
{
    String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_NAME + " FROM " + USER_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " = " + "'" + user_email + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //reads for database
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    if(c.getCount() > 0) // if cursor is not empty
    {
        String n = c.getString(0);
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

As you can see, it's returning null. And yes there is entries in the database already. Also, I tried just passing the email to the function and returning what was passed and it still gave me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to check for a value in a text column, you do not use the equal `=` sign, but rather `WHERE Column LIKE '%text%'`. Also, when saving to a database you should escape and "sanitize" strings. If you did this, then you should also be doing the same process when looking for them, else you won't find them.

I am telling you this since, even if you are sure there are entries in your table, the result of the query may be empty. You could just debug by printing the result of the `c.getCount()` call or something.

Comment: I tried debugging by printing the result of c.getCount() and it still returns null. Everything is returning null. I even returned from the function what I passed.
`
   public String findName(String user_email)
    {
        String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_NAME + " FROM " + USER_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " LIKE " + "'%" + user_email + "%';";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //reads for database
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return user_email;
`
And it still gave me a null and crash
What do you mean sanitizing strings?